# Get values from a multi value field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a field that can accept unlimited values. I want to print those values in my template.

The array that I can see with the devel module looks like this....

```
Array
(
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Dustin
                    [format] => 
                    [safe_value] => Dustin
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Jen
                    [format] => 
                    [safe_value] => Jen
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Mike
                    [format] => 
                    [safe_value] => Mike
                )

        )

)
```

What I'd like to do is have these values printed to a comma separated list like: `Dustin, Jen, Mike`

I've been using this code to print single value fields in my template but that of course isn't going to work well with a multi value field..

```
<?php echo $entityform->field_team_name['und'][0]['value']; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) will do the trick:

```
if ( ($items = field_get_items('entityform', $entityform, 'field_team_name')) ) {
  $values = array_map($items, function($x) { return $x['safe_value']; });
  $comma_separated = implode(', ', $values);
}
```

Comment: of course, make sure those `['values']` are safe to just print/echo out to the world :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its not printing out anything though. I'm printing the $comma_separated variable but its empty.. hmm.

Comment: Hmmm yeah that should work as far as I can tell...does the condition for `field_get_items` get entered? If so, what's in `$items` at that point?

Comment: Yep, $items spits out an array.. 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dustin
            [format] => 
            [safe_value] => Dustin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => Jen
            [format] => 
            [safe_value] => Jen
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => Mike
            [format] => 
            [safe_value] => Mike
        )

)

Comment: Strange, can't think of any reason why that wouldn't work. You could always loop through: `foreach ($items as $item) { $val = $item['safe_value']; }`, but the anonymous function should really do the same thing

Comment: Thanks Clive. I have it working now. This is what I ended up with... 

`foreach ($items as $item) { 
    $members = $prefix . $item['safe_value'];        
    $prefix = ', ';
    print $members; 
  }`